# Enable Nuxt source maps in production build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I recently built a universal in Nuxt and deployed it. However I keep running into this error:

```
[nuxt] Error while initializing app DOMException: "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" app.3bc9463ad06cdf9b6df1.js:formatted:2195
T23V/<
app.3bc9463ad06cdf9b6df1.js:formatted:2195
a
https://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:242000
M/<
https://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:242145
l
https://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:105265
TypeError: "n.setAttribute is not a function"
nrhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:43662xhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:54236xhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:54466xhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:54316xhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:54466xhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:54316Krhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:56066_updatehttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:34144mounthttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:63373gethttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:18466runhttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:19357Eehttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:17495tehttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:13945Zthttps://wca.findleds.com/_nuxt/vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:13447 vendor.6debe2bdce1d595803d9.js:2:13331
```

I am not getting any errors in development. I even configured a duplicate build of the production server and didn't get the error. I diff'd the `.nuxt` folders and got nothing unusually different.

Source maps would be super helpful here, but I haven't been able to get them to load. How do you enable source maps in `nuxt.config.js` when the `NODE_ENV = production`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source maps for nuxt prod build can be enabled via extending nuxt webpack configuration (see https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extend) like this:

```
export default {
  build: {
    extend(config) {
      config.devtool = 'source-map'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From reading through [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1552) I switched my non-page components using `v-if="$auth.loggedIn"` to `v-show` and this resolved the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem since switching to the nuxt $auth module. I have already replaced all v-if with v-show but I still get this error. It's quite hard to debug. Do you have any additional tips that could help me figuring this out?

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to enable source maps in nuxt production build.